# Terminal defaults to cat process

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal

I was trying to install Ruby on my mac and I seem to have failed miserably.

I tried to go through two how-to's and they didn't help.

Now whenever I open a Terminal window it automatically goes to the "cat" process saying "Last login: Thu Jan  2 11:57:46 on ttys000"

This doesn't let me do any of the normal Terminal commands (like cd)

When i stop the process with ctrl+c it say "process completed" but i can no longer type

what can i do to make my terminal default to the normal settings?

Comment: *HOW* were you trying to install Ruby? What steps did you do? Goes to *WHAT* `cat` process? Without some idea of what you did, and ideas of what is currently in your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.profile` files, we're unable to help you.

Comment: i tried to use the walkthroughs here: http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html
and here: http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyversionmanager/ss/Installing-Ruby-On-Snow-Leopard-With-Rvm.htm

Comment: We still know nothing about what you actually did.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the shell to its defaults by running `rm -i ~/.profile ~/.bash*`

To reset the Terminal application, delete `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` and then relaunch.

Comment: Don't delete them, move them somewhere out of the way, or temporarily rename them.

Comment: how would i run what you suggested?  when i try to run it nothing happens.  terminal just goes to the next line